# Euler's constant in probability mass function?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, eulers-number-e

I was messing around with PMF and thought about what'd happen if the probability of getting a success was nearly impossible, and the amount of tries approached infinity (and we only wanted 1 success).
$$f(n,p,k)=\frac{n!p^k(1-p)^{n-k}}{k!(n-k)!}\hspace{0.1cm}\Bigg|\hspace{0.3cm} n=\text{number of trials} \\ p=\text{probability of getting a success in one trial},\hspace{0.5cm}k=\text{number of successes desired} \\[5pt] f\left(\lim_{n\to\infty},\lim_{p\to 0},1\right)=\frac{1}{e}$$
Now why exactly does $e$ show up here? does it have any meaning? is the limit correct? I'm very confused and thanks in advance

Comment: How are you taking this double limit? Are you holding $np$ constant? If so, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem).

Comment: It's not at all apparent how you obtain this $1/e$ result. In particular the order of limits is unclear. If we start by evaluating at $k=1$, we have $f(p,k,1)=n p(1-p)^{n-1}.$ Then the limits $p\to 0$ and $n\to\infty$, on their own, each take $f(p,k,1)\to 0$ on their own. You do get $f(n,p,1)\to 1/e$ if $n\to\infty$ with $np=1$ held fixed, but that's not the only way to take the limit.

Comment: i assumed that $np$ would be equal to 1, since if $n$ approaches infinity, you could describe $p$ as $\frac{1}{n}$, because then it'd approach 0, the we would get $\frac{n}{n}$ which is 1, is that wrong?

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty,p\to 0, np = b} f(n,p,k) ={e^{-b} b^k\over k!}$, an instance of the Poisson distribution as the limit of binomials — the so-called Law of Rare Events.